# Nginx rewrite part of URL

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, url

i'm trying to make a redirects from URL's with option ID to URL's with option URL_key i've assigned.

I have two column table with ID i'd like to substitute and URL_key as substitute.

11337   bar
11419   restaurant
11399   cafe
15477   painting

I have these URL's coming right now:

ifab.ru/art/kartiny/location/11399/style/15477

that i would like redirect to:

ifab.ru/art/kartiny/location/cafe/style/painting

You may say i could just take all the urls from website and substitute with replace, but they are being generated automatically and each combination may be different from each other, so i would like to catch the ID and rewrite it to URL_key.

Any thoughts and solutions are appreciated.

We run our server on nginx, no apache.

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/map

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for this reference. As far as i know, map is not flexible enough to change part of url. it suits to rewrite full urls. Could you please give an example of how can i use it for my case?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
map $loc $loc_text {
    11337 bar;
    11419 restaurant;
}

map $style $style_text {
    15477 painting;
}

rewrite ^/art/kartiny/location/(?P<loc>\d+)/style/(?P<style>\d+)$ 
    /art/kartiny/location/$loc_text/style/$style_text
    redirect;
```

See also http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names

Comment: Hi, @Tobia, thank you for this solution, it seems like a working one, but i can include /art/kartiny here, it's other part of URL which i wouldn't like to monitor. I need to change only something like
<br/>
^/location/(?P<loc>\d+)/style/(?P<style>\d+)$ 
    /location/$loc_text/style/$style_text
<br/>
Is it possible?

It would be awesome if it was possible to leave only something like
<br/>
^/(?P<loc>\d+)/
/$loc_text/

Comment: You mean like this: `rewrite ^/(.*)/location/(?P<loc>\d+)/style/(?P<style>\d+)$ /$1/location/$loc_text/style/$style_text` ?